# Scrollview inside listview issue in android

Tags: android

I am adding a listview inside a scrollview in xml that xml(Screen) is loading from the middle screen. In my design I have a top part like a textview and a list view and middle part like editext and bottom part like button. Page is loading from the middle part. If it scrolls I can only see the above part. I want to load the page from above part. Can anybody tell me what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain it detailed.

Comment: "...that xml(Screen) is loading from middle screen..." : what do you mean by middle screen?question is not yet clear.

Comment: I am curios to know when already List View have Scroll feature itself, why you want to add Scroll view with ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using smoothScrollTO(0,0) to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:fillViewport="true"` as an attribute in your scrollview tag and it will fill up the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to use ScrollView with ListView. Use ListView only, you will be able to scroll the items in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
>   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
>   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
>   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
>   ScrollView.

found it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)